# DELETE query with Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete

I am running a query to delete from table.

```
delete from sps
inner join str on str.studentid = sps.studentid 
where str.studentid like '%2012%psy%' 
  and str.semesterid=2 
inner join papers on papers.id = sps.paperid 
where papers.c_id=10 
  and papers.p_semid=2
```

I don't know why it is not showing any result and giving me an error.

The error is :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
>       corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
>       'inner join str on str.studentid=sps.studentid where str.studentid like '%2012%ps'
>       at line 2

Comment: What error did you got? post it please.

Comment: What do you want to delete? (which table?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the two predicates of the two `WHERE` clauses into one `WHERE` clause at the end of your query, as described by the [Mysql `DELETE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html). Something like:

```
DELETE s 
FROM sps s
INNER JOIN str ON str.studentid = s.studentid 
INNER JOIN papers ON papers.id = s.paperid 
WHERE str.studentid LIKE '%2012%psy%' 
  AND str.semesterid = 2 
  AND papers.c_id = 10 
  AND papers.p_semid = 2
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN str ON str.studentid = sps.studentid INNER JOIN papers ON papers.id' at line 2. This is the new Error

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WHERE` clause once in a single query.
Try this query

```
DELETE sps FROM sps
INNER JOIN str ON str.studentid=sps.studentid
INNER JOIN papers ON papers.id=sps.paperid 
WHERE papers.c_id=10 AND papers.p_semid=2
AND str.studentid LIKE '%2012%psy%' AND str.semesterid=2
```

OR

```
DELETE FROM sps, str, papers 
USING sps 
      INNER JOIN str ON str.studentid=sps.studentid
      INNER JOIN papers ON papers.id=sps.paperid 
WHERE   papers.c_id=10 
    AND papers.p_semid=2
    AND str.studentid LIKE '%2012%psy%' 
    AND str.semesterid=2
```

Comment: @IPerfect Updated the answer try it.